# What is DBHammer and why is it a scheduled job on my SQL Server machine?

Tags: sql-server

First, let me say this.  I'm a programmer.  I don't know IT stuff (beyond enough to really be dangerous).

Recently the IT guy quit a client of mine, and all of a sudden, things are going very oddly on their network.

The thing I'm curious about right this second is a Job in SQL Server that appears under "Management -> SQL Server -> Jobs" on the production database called "DBHammer".  The command it appears to be running is "DBHammer..DBOlympics"

Has anyone seen this before?  I don't *think* that we have a database called DBHammer or DBOlympics, and I can't find it anywhere, but SQL Server claims that the job ran successfully and next run time is tomorrow at 3 AM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define oddly?  What types of things are you seeing?

Comment: This server has now completely flipped itself out.  When...something, wish I could define it better than this...happens, the 2nd CPU gets pegged with CPU activity and Kernel activity (the red indicator in Process Manager, can't remember the term) and the System Event Log gets filled with this message "The driver for device \Device\Scsi\viamraid1 detected a port timeout due to prolonged inactivity. All associated busses were reset in an effort to clear the condition."

Comment: Ouch, that looks more like a problem with the drive or raid controller.  Get your backups of information and/or move the drives to another machine and do backups there.  It could be that the DBHammer and DBOlympics are meant to be stress testing the system in some way, which is leading to the pegged condition.  Are you running in a RAID environment?  What Level?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wouldn't let it run without checking to see what it is.  Take a good backup of everything before you start (you may want it for evidence) and keep good notes on what you do.

What version of SQL Server?  On a 2008 R2 install I have the following jobs:

[image]

Do a right click, for the context menu on one of the jobs and choose `Properties` for this screen:

[image]

Then choose the `Steps` page:

[image]

Click the Edit button:

[image]

and you can view all of the steps in the job.   The  `Next` and `Previous` buttons can be used to navigate within the job.  If you don't like what you see, you can go to the `Schedules` page and `Edit` the schedule:

[image]

and disable the schedule:

[image]

so that it won't run anymore.

Comment: I'm the one who asked the question, but wasn't logged in at the time.  When I get a chance to get back to the machine I asked it from, I'll accept this answer.  Thanks Larry, that was great.